# How to solve HTTPotion conn_failed intermittent error

Tags: elixir

Sometime I got intermittent error`%HTTPotion.ErrorResponse{message: "{:conn_failed, :error}"}`.

```
headers = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]
HTTPotion.post(<URL>, body: body, headers: headers, timeout: 20_000, recv_timeout: 20_000)
```

If I curl the same request OR use `direct` as below, I got response successfully.

```
{:ok, worker_pid} = HTTPotion.spawn_worker_process(<URL>)
HTTPotion.post(<URL>, body: body, headers: headers,  timeout: 20_000, recv_timeout: 20_000, direct: worker_pid)
```

Comment: Have you started `:httpotion` application or have `HTTPotion.start` started manually supervised?

Comment: `:httpotion` application, not manually